# hbase-user-master.pid is not created after staring zookeeper

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I have installed `hbase` and `zookeeper` in *stand alone mode*.when i try to run `zkServer.sh start`
 command, *zookeeper* server starts fine.*But* after starting `hbase` using `start-hbase.sh` command, the 
`hbase-user-master.pid` is not created in **tmp** folder(ie. *master* is not started).Any how, **with out** starting the *zookeeper* `hbase-user-master.pid` is created in **tmp** folder.why that  **pid** is not creating after starting *zookeeper*??

here are my `conf` files:

**hbase-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
          <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
          <value>hdfs://TRAINING-21:54310/hbase</value>
    </property>  
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>/home/sensiple/hduser/zookeeper</value>
    </property>

    <property>
             <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
             <value>2181</value>
    </property>

    <property>
             <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
             <value>192.168.18.197</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**zoo.cfg:**

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/home/sensiple/hduser/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
```

Comment: I have disabled zookeepr. My HBase master is not starting, the exception is source name ugi already exist". Did you solve the problem?